# How to use EF Core Context's DBConnection object safely

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For some reason, I want to get the DBConnection object of the DBContext object.

Because the DBConnection, DBCommand and DBDataReader are disposable, I used them like this:

```
public static void Query(DBContext context)
{
    using var conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    conn.Open();
    using var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    // do something
    using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    // do something
}
```

When this method was completed, I wanted to use the DBContext object within another method. And then the DBContext object got wrong with *InvalidOperationException* : the connectionstring property has not been initialized

I try to get DBConnection in the next method which threw this exception, and found the State property was "Closed".

Does the `context.DataBase.GetDbConnection()` method return the same instance everytime?

If I do not add *using* before the conn object, like this:

```
var conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
using var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
// something just the same as above
```

Everything is OK.

Can I just do *not* dispose the DBConnection object after using it, if the DBContext object have other things to do?

Is this safe?

By the way, the DBContext object is declared by `using`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just do not dispose the DBConnection object after using it, if
>   the DBContext object have other things to do?
>
> Is this safe?

It is the right way to do that and it is safe. Don't worry about the `DbConnection` as long as the `DbContext` is disposed it will close and dispose the related `DbConnection` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you are using EF Core 3.0, you can use ".FromSqlRaw()" instead of .CreateCommand().

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var result= context.ExampleTable.FromSqlRaw("SELECT Id, Name FROM ExampleTable").ToList();
}
```

Parametered Queries are possible with

```
var result= context.ExampleTable.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * From ExampleTable Where Id= {0}", id).FirstOrDefault();
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/querying/raw-sql for more details